# How to use articles with jobs

Tags: indefinite-article

I agree that we use the indefinite article when talking about not unique jobs/occupations. But does it somehow change depending on the position of the job word in a sentence? I mean, "Builder John has won the prize". Is it common to say like this?

So, I would appreciate it if you could help me with the following sentences:

John is a builder.
Builder John has done sth. (or The builder John has done sth?)
John, the builder ..., has done sth. (or John, a builder (like a member of a group))

or, if talking about somebody who is famous
the writer Alexander Pushkin
or just writer?
or "Alexander Pushkin, a writer ... ."? or the writer?

and if talking about unique positions
The president Trump ... .
Trump, the president ... . (or just "Trump, president...")

Answer (score 1):

As Pushkin is famous, we would refer to him as *the* writer. *A writer* would be used to explain who a little-known person is.

The president of a republic is referred to as *President X* in the same way that we say *Queen Elizabeth.* We would say *Donald Trump is the President of the USA* because, as you say, it is a unique position.

As for John the builder...

*John is a builder* That is his job. *John was the builder of my house.* That's why he is significant to me. *I thanked the builder, John, for doing such a good job.* We wouldn't use 'Builder John'.  *John Smith, a builder from Portsmouth, was arrested yesterday.* That tells people who have never heard of him who he is.

Comment: Note that President Is being used as a title in President Trump, and titles have their own rules separate from jobs in general. It’s not about being unique.

Comment: We can say "The President of the United States of America, Donald Trump,..."